# In Oracle, if parallel_max_servers is set to be significantly less than the DOP can the explain plan be sub-optimal?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, parallelism

For tables that have `DEGREE DEFAULT`, the degree of parallelism (DOP) is calculated by Oracle using number of CPUs and number of threads per CPU amongst other things. As I understand it, when costing execution plans Oracle will assume the default DOP for tables with `DEGREE DEFAULT`.

At execution time, however, if `parallel_max_servers` is less than the default DOP then the number of parallel servers will be restricted and - I presume - the final execution may not go as intended by the costed execution plan and a less parallel execution plan may be preferable.

Is this correct?

Comment: `parallel_max_servers` is higher than the highest possible DOP [by default](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel005.htm#VLDBG1486) - have you turned it down?

Comment: Hi Jack - this is on a shared server managed by others. I presume they're looking to prevent a huge number of threads from kicking off. That's a great link though - hadn't come across that one before. Do you think my logic is correct? It assumes that parallel_max_servers is ignored when costing an execution plan.

Comment: I think your logic is correct in that if the parallelism is limited to below what the CBO expected when it complied the plan then *perhaps* a different plan would have been better.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a very strange thing if parallel_max_servers is set to a value below cpu_count * parallel_threads_per_cpu. I would call that a mistake by the DBA even. Let me bring to your attention a new feature of 11g (you should always mention your version, by the way), called Automatic DOP, that I have introduced in a posting here:
http://uhesse.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/automatic-dop-in-11gr2/